# Click listener inside google maps info window

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

This is a project I did some months ago in React.js, hosted on Github pages. I visited today, and the click listener I have on the infowindow is broken. The error I get is: read property 'addEventListener' of null, which means React thinks my selector is not added to the DOM.

This is the live version:

```
https://stamatisdeli.github.io/Neighborhood-map/
```

this is my repo:

```
https://github.com/StamatisDeli/Neighborhood-map/blob/master/src/App.js
```

in line 118 I call openModal

More errors occur when I click in a list item, but first things first.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably move the offending code inside the [`domready`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/info-window#InfoWindow.domready) event of the `infowindow` so you are sure its contents are available.

so change the

```
self.openModal()
```

line to

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
      self.openModal()
});
```

Comment: It seems to work, thanks! Any idea why the delayed malfunction?